# How to get the max-innerHeight when browser is not 100% (size)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Suppose `window.innerHeight = 978px` when the browser is 100% (not full screen).

However, when resizing the browser, `window.innerHeight` value will decrease.

So how to get the `height = 978px` when when the browser is not 100%? (I want to get this to calculate something in js script)

**Update**

I have an idea how to get this,
the script should be

> `window.screen.availHeight - window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight`

But, for Safari, the script should be

> `window.screen.availHeight - window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight - 3`

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to look for:

```
screen.height
```

The issue is I'm not sure you can use get the height of the start-bar (assuming it's windows and on the bottom). Otherwise this will probably be a good starting point.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp

Comment: my Chrome browser: `window.innerHeight = 978px (when 100%)`, `screen.height = 1080px (always)`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure without actually maxing a window you can determine how much screenspace is taken up by the chrome menu/nav bars etc and whatever windows has on the bottom. These will tend to be out of the scope of your local JS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
```